# Mod page speed not combining css and js when used with JSR 286 portlets

Tags: performance, pagespeed

My application uses jsr 286 portlets. My application is a single page application and is built with 10 jsr 286 portlets each has its own view.
In each view I am referring to css and js which is required for that portlet alone
When i enabled mod page speed with all the combining css and js filters enabled, i still see all the js and css are loading with out getting combined into single css and js call.
Can you please suggest if this is expected behavior or if there is any setting/configuration to overcome this.
Appreciate your suggestion/recommendation.

Comment: Please show us your configurations.

Comment: This is the configuration I am using for combinig js and css ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css,combine_javascript,sprite_images,rewrite_images,insert_img_dimensions,move_css_to_head,rewrite_css

Comment: ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css,combine_javascript,sprite_images,rewrite_images,insert_img_dimensions,move_css_to_head,rewrite_css